# Triggers after insert

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, database-trigger

I have a table that has the following columns, and I cannot modify the schema (i.e. I can't modify the table or add an identity field).

What I want is to create a trigger to update one column to treat it as an identity field.

```
accountno      firstname    lastname      keyField
jku45555       John          Doe          123
```

Now what I want is when I insert the next record, I grab the `KeyFieldId` of the previous record and update the newly inserted record to be 124 (keep in mind this a `Varchar` field).

I need the best possible way of doing this, and like I said modifying the table is not an option. Thanks!

Comment: Why can you not add an identity column out of curiosity?

Comment: I know exactly what you are saying but this is an API that i have no control of we did this in the past but now i am upgrading to a newer version and every customized field will be deleted and the only way this will work is to just use the one field i mentioned since we already have moved the data from that customized it identity field to this one and now all i need is update that field. PmbAustin has actually put a straight forward example. but yeah my hands are tied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do something like this... For a table named "Foo", with two columns, First Name and KeyFieldId (both varchar), this trigger will  do what you want:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- These lines will create a test table and test data
--DEBUG: CREATE TABLE Foo (FirstName varchar(20), KeyFieldId varchar(10))
--DEBUG: INSERT INTO Foo VALUES ('MyName', '145')
--    
CREATE TRIGGER test_Trigger ON Foo
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @maxKeyFieldId int;
    SELECT @maxKeyFieldId = MAX(CAST(KeyFieldId AS int)) FROM Foo;
    WITH RowsToInsert AS (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (CAST(KeyFieldId AS int))) AS RowNum
        FROM inserted
    ) INSERT INTO Foo (FirstName, KeyFieldId)
        SELECT FirstName, @maxKeyFieldId + RowNum
            FROM RowsToInsert;

END
```

Things to note here:

1. Create an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger
2. Find the "max" value of the INTEGER value of your KeyFieldID
3. Create a CTE that selects everything from the 'inserted' collection
4. Add a column to the CTE for a Row Number
5. Do the actual INSERT by adding row number to the max KeyFieldID

Comment: Thank you, you just put me on the right track,Shouldn't i be doing an update since the record is inserted from the CRM and now all i need is update the KEYFIELD to the maxkeyfieldid+ RowNum

Comment: The INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger runs *instead* of inserting, so the code should do an insert.  AFTER INSERT runs after inserting, and there you'd do an update, but in this case, it seems more efficient to avoid having to do an insert and turn around and immediately do an update... just insert the correct data to start.